# When running the webdriver, the Chrome browser opens and closes the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, rpa

I am unable to open a chrome address through the selenium library webdriver. The page opens but closes quickly.

I am executing the python instructions below and the Chrome browser opens and closes immediately without generating an error message in the terminal.

```
from selenium import webdriver as opcoesSelenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

navegador = opcoesSelenium.Chrome()

navegador.get("https://rpachallengeocr.azurewebsites.net/")
```

My Chrome browser version is 119.0.6045.160 and selenium is 4.15.2.

I can't find the webdriver for this version at [https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads](https://stackoverflow.com).

So I used the instructions below to install the webdriver compatible with my browser version, however, it did not solve the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("http://www.python.org")

driver.close()
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: driver.close() will close the browser.  It's working as expected.  (You should use driver.quit(), though... close will only to close the current tab/window... if it's that only one, it may also quit the driver, but not all drivers will do that)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.